# Unexpected redirect url due to 2 similar routings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

My application uses multiple routes. Here are two relevant ones:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "MyRoute",
                url: "Flow",
                defaults: new { controller = "MyCtrl1", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MyCtrl2", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Now I have an `Action` that returns:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Flow", new {Id = <currId>});
```

Now the framework probably does it's optimizations(The `"Default"` route has a default `action` named `"Index"`) and the redirect url **I get** is:

```
https://<host>/Flow?Id=<currId>
```

While the **expected** url is:

```
https://<host>/Flow/Index?Id=<currId>
```

My problem is that I want the `"Default"` route to handle the request and the `"MyRoute"` handles it.
It looks like the framework did the optimization and forgot checking if the intended route changed after the optimization.

My Questions:

1. Do you see something wrong with my routes? Or is this a framework bug?
2. Is there any way to prevent these optimizations and return `Flow/Index`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **return RedirectToAction()** use **return RedirectToRoute()**. Where you can set the custom route name in **return RedirectToRoute("MyRoute")**.

Refer this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4XDc110313-return-View%28%29-vs-return-RedirectToAction%28%29-vs-return-Redirect%28%29-vs-return-RedirectToRoute%28%29.html

Comment: But I want to redirect to an Action(and not the default route's action). If I specify return RedirectToRoute("Default") where do I enter the controller\action?
P.s. this doesn't look to elegant even if it "works". I'm sure there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyCtrl2", new {Id = <currId>});

return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyCtrl", new {id= <currId>});
```

Comment: I want to redirect to Flow/Index and not to the default MyCtrl1/Index.

Comment: routes.MapRoute(name: "MyRoute",
                url: "Flow/Index",
                defaults: new { controller = "MyCtrl1", action = "Index" });

 return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyCtrl1", new {Id = <currId>});

try this. it shold work.

Answer (score 0):

Take the default action out of your default route. This will force it to always be specified in the URL created:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "MyRoute",
            url: "Flow",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCtrl1", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCtrl2", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: But I do need the default route...Otherwise that was an easy solution. BTW after trying lot's of things I've understood that the framework will not choose the "best" but the first suitable routing. Now I understand the it hard to define a "router comparer" - I was looking for a way to aviod the url creation with optimizations.

Comment: Ok, no problem. If you only need the default root for the homepage, you could add a root for just that: routes.MapRoute(name: "Homepage",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCtrl2", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

Comment: It's not only for my home-page. I have a marketing site that recieves requests from multiple locations and thats why I need a default action to handle them(every url has different params..).
My ugly solution was the change the Flow/Index action to Flow/FlowIndex..It was the easiest(and ugliest) way to handle this specific problem.